# Question 6.11 : Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self studying **Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory** and I am completely stuck while solving **Problem 6.11**. The question reads:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, and let $S$ be a subset containing more than $\frac{n}{2}$elements of $G$. Prove that for each $g$ in $G$ there exist elements $a$ and $b$ in $S$ such that $ab=g$.

**My attempt:**

Assume, on the contrary, $\exists$ $g \in G$ such that $g \neq ab$ $\forall$ $a\in S$ and $b \in S$.

Let $S = \{s_1,s_2,\cdots, s_m\} $ where $m > \frac{n}{2}$ and $G=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots, s_m, t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_{n-m}\} $.

**How do I proceed ?**

Any help will be highly apreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|S|+|S^{-1}g| > n/2+n/2= |G|$$
where $S^{-1}g := \{ a^{-1} g | a \in S\}$
Besides, $S$ and $S^{-1}g$ are subsets of $G$, hence
$$S \cap (S^{-1}g) \ne \emptyset$$
Hence the conclusion.